# How to animate drawing edges with JUNG

Tags: java, swing, jung

I'm new to JUNG
I have a FRLayout that represents a network topology with key nodes or vertices that are color as red and the other vertices blue 
The edges from the starting node to the end node are blue
I want to be to demonstrate an animation of the path to the end node.
How can animate drawing the edges from a start_node to end_node with a specified time interval?  Can you provide or reference an example?

Answer (score 3):

You could attach a keyframe to your Edge data. Then, every time you draw (using a transformer) you can use the keyframe to adjust the gradient of the edge:

```
RenderContext<V, E> context = vv.getRenderContext();
context.setEdgeDrawPaintTransformer(new KeyframeGradientTransformer());

public class KeyframeGradientTransformer() implements Transformer<E, Paint> {
        @Override
        public Paint transform(Edge edge) {
            // TODO: Here you would determine the gradient information
            // based on the edge.getKeyframe().
            Paint gradient = new GradientPaint(...);
            return gradient;
        }
}
```

EDIT:

I wrote up a quick example:

[image]

This animates from one vertex to another (along one edge). If you want to animate going through multiple vertices, that will require more logic. However, this looks pretty cool and should give you a start. If you (or anyone else) need more comments, just let me know and I can try and make it more clear.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.LinearGradientPaint;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.apache.commons.collections15.Factory;
import org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer;

import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.generators.random.EppsteinPowerLawGenerator;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.Layout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.SpringLayout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.SparseMultigraph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.util.Pair;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.VisualizationViewer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JPanel content = new JPanel();

                // Set up the graph and the display.
                int numV = 70;
                int numE = 50;
                EppsteinPowerLawGenerator<String, String> gen = new EppsteinPowerLawGenerator<String, String>(
                        new GraphFactory(), new CountFactory(),
                        new CountFactory(), numV, numE, 10);
                Graph<String, String> graph = gen.create();
                Layout<String, String> layout = new SpringLayout<String, String>(
                        graph);
                VisualizationViewer<String, String> vv = new VisualizationViewer<String, String>(
                        layout);
                vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeStrokeTransformer(
                        new Transformer<String, Stroke>() {

                            @Override
                            public Stroke transform(String edge) {
                                return new BasicStroke(1.5f);
                            }
                        });

                content.add(vv);

                frame.setContentPane(content);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                // Animate the edges!
                AnimationTimerTask at = new AnimationTimerTask(vv);
                Timer timer = new Timer();
                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(at, 10, 30);
            }

        });
    }

    static class AnimationTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        private final double width = 0.1; // Size of the colored line.
        private final double stepsize = 0.01;
        private double keyframe = 0 + width; // Between 0.0 and 1.0
        private VisualizationViewer<String, String> vv = null;

        public AnimationTimerTask(VisualizationViewer<String, String> vv) {
            this.vv = vv;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeDrawPaintTransformer(
                    new Transformer<String, Paint>() {

                        @Override
                        public Paint transform(String edge) {
                            // Find both points of the edge.
                            Pair<String> vs = vv.getGraphLayout().getGraph()
                                    .getEndpoints(edge);
                            Point2D p1 = vv.getGraphLayout().transform(
                                    vs.getFirst());
                            Point2D p2 = vv.getGraphLayout().transform(
                                    vs.getSecond());

                            // This code won't handle self-edges.
                            if (p1.equals(p2)) {
                                return Color.red;
                            }

                            Color[] colors = { Color.gray, Color.red,
                                    Color.gray };
                            float start = (float) Math.max(0.0, keyframe
                                    - width);
                            float end = (float) Math.min(1.0, keyframe + width);
                            float[] fractions = { start, (float) keyframe, end };
                            return new LinearGradientPaint(p1, p2, fractions,
                                    colors);
                        }

                    });
            vv.repaint();
            keyframe += stepsize;
            keyframe %= 1.0;
        }
    }

    static class GraphFactory implements Factory<Graph<String, String>> {

        @Override
        public Graph<String, String> create() {
            return new SparseMultigraph<String, String>();
        }
    }

    static class CountFactory implements Factory<String> {

        private int count = 0;

        @Override
        public String create() {
            return String.valueOf(count++);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I've taken a bit of heat for this before so: this requires the JUNG library. If you don't have it, you can't run the SSCCEE.

Comment: Could you please give more details on the keyframe

Comment: @Nabegh Take a look at the edit - hopefully it makes sense. (I'm not sure how efficient this is, but it seems to work for < 500 vertices and edges.)

Comment: this is very helpful. Thanks. I believe that in order to change the edge stroke, I will need to implement setEdgeStrokeTransformer using the same logic?

Comment: @Nabegh Yes, I actually do change the edge stroke in this example as well - but only because it was hard to see with the original skinny lines. You can see where I add the transformer right after I create the VisualizationViewer.