# JUNG edge label and shape

Tags: java, graph, jung

Is it possible to change the edge shape in JUNG? For example, I would like to have the edge change it's color gradually in a way similar to a progress bar. What about the edge label font size?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, sort of...  Also - I'm not sure which version of JUNG you're using, but this works in the latest JUNG 2 release (I realize JUNG 3 might be under development currently, but last time I checked, it wasn't stable enough to be used for production-level code).

**1.  Labelling:**  First, you need to implement the `Transformer<EdgeType,Font>` interface that converts your edge instances into `Font` instances.  Then call `[VisualizationViewer instance].getRenderContext().setEdgeFontTransformer([Transformer<EdgeType,Font> instance])`.

**2.  Color/Stroke Customization:**  This is a little trickier, because the only way you can have this change color gradually (that I am aware of) is by creating a `Transformer<EdgeType,Paint>` that returns different paints for edge type instances over time.  There are several transformers used for edges - these control the draw, the fill, and the Stroke, and have similar method names like the one mentioned for the labeller in step 1.  You will either need to control when the graph panel repaints manually or ensure that JUNG's animation renderer is turned on so that repaints happen continuously.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using JUNG 2. How do I check the status of the animation renderer?

Comment: I believe it's something like this:

    `DefaultVisualizationModel<Vertex,Edge> model = new DefaultVisualizationModel<>([layout instance]);
    ((VisRunner)visModel.getRelaxer()).resume();`

Comment: I answered a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404724/how-to-animate-drawing-edges-with-jung/13592798#13592798 as prompted by the OP.